# create labels for interval

Tags: r, cut

I am trying to create a label with `cut` and here is the example

```
> cut(c(1,5,10,15,160),c(0,5,10,15,Inf))
[1] (0,5]    (0,5]    (5,10]   (10,15]  (15,Inf]
Levels: (0,5] (5,10] (10,15] (15,Inf]
```

I wanted to automatically create labels like this

```
"1~5" "6~10" "11~15" "15+"
```

Is there any way I can do it automatically?

Comment: If the answers solved your problem you should accept it. It provides closure for future readers and helps them to understand which solution actually worked. If the answer doesn't solve your problem you should get it cleared by engaging with the answerer or provide a better/different example to demonstrate your actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this automatically without manually specifying the labels you can do the manipulation as :

```
vec <- c(1,5,10,15,160)
breaks <- c(0,5,10,15,Inf)
n <- length(breaks)
labels <- paste(breaks[-n] + 1, breaks[-1], sep = '~')
labels[length(labels)] <- paste0(breaks[n - 1], '+')
cut(vec,breaks, labels)

#[1] 1~5   1~5   6~10  11~15 15+  
#Levels: 1~5 6~10 11~15 15+
```